# Fasta file uploads and pdf downloads

Tags: file-upload, shiny, alignment, fasta

I have to traduce a code to another one in which you can upload the fasta file chosen by you and download the alignment in pdf format. I have tried during a long time and I cannot achieve it. 
The code (you have to upload a specific file) is:

```
   library(shiny)      
   library(msa) 

   runApp(list(

   mySequences <- readDNAStringSet("/Users/-----/dna3.fas", format = "fasta"),
   myFirstAlignment <- msa(mySequences),


   ui = fluidPage(downloadButton('downloadPDF')),   
   server = function(input, output) {  
   output$downloadPDF = downloadHandler(  
  filename = 'myreport.pdf',  
  content = function(file) {  
    msaPrettyPrint(  
      myFirstAlignment  
      , file = 'myreport.pdf'  
      , output="pdf"  
      , showNames="none"  
      , showLogo="top"  
      , consensusColor="BlueRed"  
      , logoColors="accessible area"  
      , askForOverwrite=FALSE)   
    file.rename("myreport.pdf", file) 

  },
  contentType = 'application/pdf'
   )
   }
   ))
```

II would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service, so we can help you to port a code between two languages but we need you to tell us what you have achieved and where you are stuck (error message ? what is not working ?)

Comment: Maybe I had not explained well my problem. II need a code that allows to choose the file that the user wants. No, one fixed.